# How to test Angular component's observable error?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, angular-test

I want to test a component will render a ErrorComponent if one of the service or Gql fails, but I'm having trouble mocking the error where it triggers the `catchError()` block.
Where do I mock that error? Inside the providers array? Using spyOn ? I tried both but not getting the results I want.

Component's `ngOnInit()` will set `this.loading = isLoading` and `this.data$ = this.getData()`

Inside getData()

```js
combineLatest([
serviceA.get(),
serviceB.get(),
GqlC.fetch(),
GqlD.fetch(),
]).pipe(
      map(
        ([a,b,c,d]) => ({
            a,
         name: b[c],
         age : d
        })
      ),
      tap(() => {
        this.loading = isSuccess;
      }),
      catchError((e) => {
        this.loading = isFailure;
        return throwError(() => e);
      })
)
```

How do I mock an error returned from service or GQL to trigger the catchError block ?

Inside Spec

```js
describe('aComponent error state', () => {
  let component;
  let fixture;
  let controller: ApolloTestingController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [aComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: serviceA,
          useValue: new mockServiceA({ mock }),},
        { provide: serviceB,
          useValue: new mockServiceB(mock), },
        { provide: APOLLO_TESTING_CACHE,
          useValue: new InMemoryCache({ addTypename: true }),},
      ],
      imports: [Module....],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(aComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    controller = TestBed.inject(ApolloTestingController);
    fixture.detectChanges()
  });
  it('should render ERROR_COMPONENT', () => {

  });
});
```

I tried `spyOn(component['GqlC'],'fetch').and.returnValue(throwError(()=>new Error('mockError')))`
but I'm not getting any error component rendered at all.

Thank you for any inputs, I'm very new to angular and testing in general any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are `GqlC` and `GqlD` defined?

Comment: Immediately before `map()`, add `tap(x => console.log('getData observable receiving %o', x)),`  My hunch is that you aren't properly mocking all, and combineLatest only emits after *each* of the inner observables have emitted anything.

Comment: @JSmart523 I think you are right I am not properly mocking my GQL =\ 
Do I add it into the provider array and pass in the expected response as useValue?

Comment: First, verify that every observable within your combineLatest is actually emitting anything. try appending `.map((o$, index) => o$.pipe(tap(x => console.log('combineLatestObservables[ %i ] emitting %s', index, x === undefined ? 'undefined' : JSON.stringify(x)))))` to the array within your combineLatest, then run it and check the console to verify that everything emits at least once? If everything is emitting at least once except for `GqlC.fetch()` then we've verified my hunch is wrong, but if my hunch is right then it doesn't matter if/how you mock GqlC.fetch() yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your mocks need to return appropriate Observables. For this particular test, have the service `get` methods and GqlC's `fetch` method return `of(null)` to make sure they emit, and have GqlD's `fetch` method return an Observable which errors out with `throwError()`.